# Solving the Hanoi Puzzle with Recursion

Tags: c++, computer-science

So here I have a program that shows the simulation of solving the Hanoi puzzle. My program works fine for the most part but does not terminate when it should. It should terminate once all discs are on the C peg (C C C), but mine continues to a fourth disc which is not given. There should only be three discs. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int num = 3;
const char from_peg = 'A';
const char to_peg = 'B';
const char temp_peg = 'C';

char position[num];
void moveDiscs(int num,int disc,char source,char dest, char spare){
    if (disc == 0){
        position[disc]=dest;
        cout<<"Moved disc "<<disc+1<<" to peg "<<dest;
        cout<<" ( ";
        for(int i = 0;i<num;i++){
            cout<<position[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<")"<<endl;
    }else{
        moveDiscs(num,disc-1,source,spare,dest);
        position[disc]=dest;
        cout<<"Moved disc "<<disc+1<<" to peg "<<dest;
        cout<<" ( ";
                for(int i = 0;i<num;i++){
                    cout<<position[i]<<" ";
                }
                cout<<")"<<endl;
        moveDiscs(num,disc-1,spare,dest,source);
    }
}
int main() {

    cout<<"Starting Position for 3 discs are (";
    for(int i = 0;i<num;i++){
        position[i]='A';
        cout<<position[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<")"<<endl;


    moveDiscs(3,3,from_peg,to_peg,temp_peg);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Starting Position for 3 discs are (A A A )
Moved disc 1 to peg C ( C A A )
Moved disc 2 to peg B ( C B A )
Moved disc 1 to peg B ( B B A )
Moved disc 3 to peg C ( B B C )
Moved disc 1 to peg A ( A B C )
Moved disc 2 to peg C ( A C C )
Moved disc 1 to peg C ( C C C )
Moved disc 4 to peg B ( C C C )
Moved disc 1 to peg B ( B C C )
Moved disc 2 to peg A ( B A C )
Moved disc 1 to peg A ( A A C )
Moved disc 3 to peg B ( A A B )
Moved disc 1 to peg C ( C A B )
Moved disc 2 to peg B ( C B B )
Moved disc 1 to peg B ( B B B )
```

Comment: `position[disc]=dest;` modifies `position` using an out of bounds index in the `else` block in the first call from `main`.

Comment: Looks like the if block is checking for disc 0-3 and in the else it ends up outputting disc+1. Not going to 'give' the answer but looking at how you compare the discs and output should put you on the right track.

Comment: [Aren't vectors fun?](http://ideone.com/5MjTjb) -- Instant diagnosis of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @Das pointed out your disc starts at 0, but you pass the number of `discs = 3` the total of discs from `0` to `3` is actually 4 (same mistake usually happens with array length). You should actually set `discs` to be equal to 2.